Correcting Coordinate Misalignment When Casting Rays from Touch Position on RenderTexture in Unity and Meta Quest
I am developing a VR application for Meta Quest using Unity. In this application, the user interacts using a controller, and the user's hand is visually represented in the virtual space.
Objective:
I want to cast a ray into the virtual space corresponding to the point touched by the hand on an object (hereafter referred to as the "panel") that has a RenderTexture showing part of the virtual space. For debugging purposes, a cube with scale (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) is displayed at the hit position for 0.1 seconds. Eventually, I plan to activate a particle system on the cube existing at the hit position.
Additionally, the camera that renders to the RenderTexture is attached to other players and is always in motion.
Current Issue:
Currently, touching the panel does not trigger any actions. Using a previous method, a cube is indeed created when touched, but the coordinates where the ray is cast are significantly misaligned.
Referenced Articles:
How do you get the texture coordinate hit by the mouse on a UI raw image in Unity?
Method to display effects on objects touched via RenderTexture (Japanese)
The second link is from a question I previously asked. With this method, a cube is generated upon touch, but the coordinates where the ray is cast are greatly misaligned.
Code:
Here is the main code attached to the panel. Any suggestions or modifications to correct the issue would be greatly appreciated.
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    public Camera displayRenderCamera; // Camera that renders to the RenderTexture
    private RawImage displayGameObject; // GameObject displaying the RenderTexture
    private Vector3? colliderPoint = null; // Intersection point with the collider

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool gripHeld = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryHandTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        bool triggerNotPressed = !OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);

        if (gripHeld && triggerNotPressed && colliderPoint != null) // Holding grip and not pressing trigger (pointing gesture)
        {
            InteractWithRenderTexture();
        }
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    private void InitializeCameraAndPanel()
    {
        PhotonView[] allPhotonViews = FindObjectsOfType<PhotonView>();

        foreach (PhotonView view in allPhotonViews)
        {
            if (view.Owner != null)
            {
                if (view.Owner.ActorNumber != PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject camera = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Head/ViewCamera")?.gameObject;
                    if (camera != null)
                    {
                        displayRenderCamera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
                        Debug.Log(displayRenderCamera);
                    }
                }
                else if (view.Owner.ActorNumber == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject panel = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Panel/Panel")?.gameObject;
                    if (panel != null)
                    {
                        displayGameObject = panel.GetComponent<RawImage>();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void InteractWithRenderTexture()
    {
        if (colliderPoint == null) return;

        Vector3 worldSpaceHitPoint = colliderPoint.Value;

        Vector2 localHitPoint = displayGameObject.rectTransform.InverseTransformPoint(worldSpaceHitPoint);

        var rect = displayGameObject.rectTransform.rect;
        Vector2 textureCoord = localHitPoint - rect.min;
        textureCoord.x *= displayGameObject.uvRect.width / rect.width;
        textureCoord.y *= displayGameObject.uvRect.height / rect.height;
        textureCoord += displayGameObject.uvRect.min;

        Ray ray = displayRenderCamera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(textureCoord.x, textureCoord.y, 0));

        // Debug: Show a red cube at the touch location
        Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(2.0f);
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = point;
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        Destroy(cube, 0.1f);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 10.0f))
        {
            if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent<CubeManager>(out var cubeManager))
            {
                cubeManager.StartParticleSystem();
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
        {
            var plane = new Plane(transform.forward, transform.position);

            colliderPoint = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(other.bounds.center);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
        {
            colliderPoint = null;
        }
    }
}


Project Reproduction Method
This project is a VR multiplayer using PUN2. Therefore, we will create an environment where players can coexist in the VR space. I referred to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHWuTBmT1oI&t=1s) to create it.
In PUN2, the NetworkPlayer prefab is stored under Asset/Resources. The hierarchy of the NetworkPlayer prefab is as shown in the image.
https://i.sstatic.net/bZnHD7gU.png
The Panel moves according to the left hand movement and can stay in place by pressing a button. The ViewPanel under Head is placed to render the player’s view onto the RenderTexture attached to the opponent’s Panel. The inspector of the Panel is as shown in the image. The PanelManager is as mentioned above.
https://i.sstatic.net/b3pIREUr.png
These are the steps to reproduce this project
I've revisited the RenderTexture settings to ensure the virtual space is rendered correctly.
How should I modify the code to accurately cast rays based on the touch position?
Thank you for your assistance!

Problem and Solution
The issue was that the Panel object did not have a RawImage component attached. Additionally, the Width and Height of the RectTransform needed to be changed from 100 to 1.
Here is the edited portion of the code:
Vector2 localHitPoint = displayGameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(colliderPoint.Value);
var rect = displayGameObject.rectTransform.rect;
Vector2 textureCoord = localHitPoint - rect.min;
textureCoord.x *= displayGameObject.uvRect.width / rect.width;
textureCoord.y *= displayGameObject.uvRect.height / rect.height;
textureCoord += displayGameObject.uvRect.min;
textureCoord = new Vector2(1 - textureCoord.x, 1 - textureCoord.y + 0.1f);

Complete Code
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    public Camera displayRenderCamera; // Camera writing the image to the RenderTexture
    private RawImage displayGameObject; // GameObject displaying the RenderTexture
    private Vector3? colliderPoint = null;
    private bool isCooldown = false;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool gripHeld = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryHandTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);
        bool triggerNotPressed = !OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch);

        if (gripHeld && triggerNotPressed)
        {
            InteractWithRenderTexture();
        }
        InitializeCameraAndPanel();
    }

    private void InteractWithRenderTexture()
    {
        if (!colliderPoint.HasValue || isCooldown) return;

        Vector2 localHitPoint = displayGameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(colliderPoint.Value);
        var rect = displayGameObject.rectTransform.rect;
        Vector2 textureCoord = localHitPoint - rect.min;
        textureCoord.x *= displayGameObject.uvRect.width / rect.width;
        textureCoord.y *= displayGameObject.uvRect.height / rect.height;
        textureCoord += displayGameObject.uvRect.min;
        textureCoord = new Vector2(1 - textureCoord.x, 1 - textureCoord.y + 0.1f);

        Ray ray = displayRenderCamera.ViewportPointToRay(textureCoord);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10.0f))
        {
            var cubeManager = hit.transform.GetComponent<CubeManager>();
            if (cubeManager != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ActivateWithCooldown(cubeManager));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ActivateWithCooldown(CubeManager cubeManager)
    {
        isCooldown = true;
        cubeManager.StartParticleSystem();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        isCooldown = false;
    }

    private void InitializeCameraAndPanel()
    {
        PhotonView[] allPhotonViews = FindObjectsOfType<PhotonView>();

        foreach (PhotonView view in allPhotonViews)
        {
            if (view.Owner != null)
            {
                if (view.Owner.ActorNumber != PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject camera = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Head/ViewCamera")?.gameObject;
                    if (camera != null)
                    {
                        displayRenderCamera = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
                    }
                }
                else if (view.Owner.ActorNumber == PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber)
                {
                    GameObject panel = view.gameObject.transform.Find("Panel/Panel")?.gameObject;
                    if (panel != null)
                    {
                        displayGameObject = panel.GetComponent<RawImage>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Panel/Panel not found on my object");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("rightHand"))
        {
            var plane = new Plane(transform.forward, transform.position);
            colliderPoint = plane.ClosestPointOnPlane(other.transform.position);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "rightHand")
        {
            colliderPoint = null;
        }
    }
}

